# How to redirect secondary URL to primary URL using Tuckey URLRewrite Filter?

Tags: java, redirect, url-rewriting, dns, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I've two domain names `primary.com` and `secondary.com`. Both point to the same app. The secondary should always be redirected to primary.

So I've used [Tuckey URL Rewrite Filter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to do the domain redirection.

My requirements are:

1. `primary.com` redirected to `www.primary.com`
2. `secondary.com` redirected to `www.secondary.com`
3. `www.secondary.com` redirected to `www.primary.com`

Here are the rules:

```
<!-- non WWW to WWW -->
    <rule>
        <name>Primary Domain Name Check</name>
        <condition name="host" operator="notequal">www.primary.com</condition>
        <from>^(.*)</from>
        <to type="redirect">http://www.primary.com$1</to>
    </rule>

    <!-- non WWW to WWW -->
    <rule>
        <name>Secondary Domain Name Check</name>
        <condition name="host" operator="notequal">www.secondary.com</condition>
        <from>^(.*)</from>
        <to type="redirect">http://www.sesondary.com$1</to>
    </rule>

    <!-- Secondary to Primary -->
    <rule>
        <name>Redirection</name>
        <condition name="host" operator="equal">www.secondary.com</condition>
        <from>^(.*)</from>
        <to type="redirect">http://www.primary.com$1</to>
    </rule>
```

But I've this feeling that this will loop infinitely. What am I doing wrong?
Can someone please guide me. I'm stuck. :(